# How to disable Android Back Button if it brings back to the react-navigation application home page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, expo, react-native, react-navigation

In a react-native application, I use react-navigation 5.

I have two mode `simple` and `pro` with a switch in the upper right corner to go from a mode to another.

By default the mode is `simple`, if I click on the switch I navigate to `pro`. I can then access all the pages for the `pro`.

When I use the **Android** back button, I normally go back to previous route. I want to disable the back button so it never goes back from `pro` to `simple`.

How is that possible ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on your navigator. I assume you are using Stack Navigator, in that case instead of doing something like `navigation.navigate('Pro')`, do `navigation.replace('Pro')` so that the Pro screen replaces Simple screen and stays the first screen in navigation stack so there is nowhere to go back from it.

Otherwise if you still want to hack into back Android button, read this https://reactnavigation.org/docs/custom-android-back-button-handling. This isn't really a solution to your problem because you would still be able to go back by, for example, accidentally dispatching back navigation action (or calling `navigation.goBack()`) or by swiping from the edge of the screen on iOS